# "Multiplexing" stdout and stderr in /usr/bin/logger

Tags: linux, bash, cron, pipe

I recently found out about /usr/bin/logger and I find it very good.

I noticed that it contains a priority argument (-p) (facility.info, facility.alert, etc..).

So if I want to log just stdin I do it that way :

```
stuff | logger -p cron.info
```

To log just stderr, that way :

```
stuff 2>&1 > /dev/null | logger -p cron.err
```

To log both stdout and stderr :

```
stuff 2> >(logger -p cron.err) | logger -p cron.info
```

I am wondering if there's a more concise way to do this, to avoid bunch of copy paste.

Is there a way achieve that kind of stuff instead ?

```
logging -F cron -s info -e err stuff
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be quite easy if the desired syntax was

```
logging cron info err stuff
```

In such case use the following function:

```
logging() {
    if [ "$#" -lt 4 ]; then
        echo "Too few arguments." >&2
        return 1
    else
        local prefix postfix1 postfix2
        prefix="$1"
        postfix1="$2"
        postfix2="$3"
        shift 3
        "$@" 2> >(logger -p "$prefix.$postfix2") | logger -p "$prefix.$postfix1"
    fi
}
```

Notes:

- You can build a standalone script instead.
- Parsing `-F`, `-s`, `-e` is possible, although not as straightforward as the above [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)-y approach.